# Gas Guzzlers Extreme. Online with friends

Tags: gas-guzzlers

Is there a way to play Gas Guzzlers Extreme online with friends on steam? I am unable to find a way.

**EDIT** when I say online with friends I mean one of the group hosts a game, the rest of the group connects to it, and the whole group plays alone without any external people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can create your own server and then your friends can connect to you with your IP address. Here is a nice guide to create your private server.

[FAQ and Private Server Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=187546252)